# OR-Tools Nurse scheduling shift_scheduling_sat.py questions/problems

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools

I am trying to use Google's OR-Tools or more specifically the example [shift_scheduling_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py) which was more comprehensive and is closer to the features that I want. The problem I need to be done is still the same (distribution of workers into set shifts) and I am just having trouble adding the things I want. For example, I want to set the number of workers in a single shift to be only one, as with the simpler example shown in [their guide](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling), which is done by:

```
for d in all_days:
    for s in all_shifts:
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

Which I could maybe do, but the example itself has a method wherein I can set the number of workers in a given workday:

```
weekly_cover_demands = [
    (2, 3, 1),  # Monday
    (2, 3, 1),  # Tuesday
    (2, 2, 2),  # Wednesday
    (2, 3, 1),  # Thursday
    (2, 2, 2),  # Friday
    (1, 2, 3),  # Saturday
    (1, 3, 1),  # Sunday
]
```

So I tried setting all of their values to: `(1,1,1)` indicating that only one worker should be selected for the specified shift and to comment out the line indicating the constraint on the number of rest per week a worker should have:

```
# Weekly sum constraints on shifts days:
#     (shift, hard_min, soft_min, min_penalty,
#             soft_max, hard_max, max_penalty)
weekly_sum_constraints = [
    # Constraints on rests per week.
    # removing constraints on rests
    #(0, 1, 2, 7, 2, 3, 4),
    # At least one night-shift per week (penalized). At most 4 (hard).
    (3, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 0),
]
```

The solution, however, took some time so I had to add the `solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds` variable to limit the time involved searching for the solution, which should theoretically be easy. The result is as follows:

```
          M T W T F S S M T W T F S S M T W T F S S 
worker 0: O M O M O O N N O M O O M O O N N O O A O
worker 1: O M N N O O M O O A O N N O O M O O A O O
worker 2: M A O O A O O A O O A O O N N O O A O O A
worker 3: M A O A O O A O O M O O A O O A O O M O O
worker 4: A A O O N N O O A O O A O O A O O N N O O
worker 5: A O M O O M O O N N N O O M O O M O O M O
worker 6: O O A A O A O O M O O M O O M O O M O O M
worker 7: N N O O M O O M O O M O O A O O A O O N N
```

With the first two days having two workers in several shifts and the rest being correct (O being a 'day-off'). Why did it didn't work in the first two days and not the rest of the days?

I feel like the simpler example would be the one on their guide page but it is lacking for my needs. I still have lots of problems and questions about this such as;

1. How does one go about making their own constraint? I could somewhat understand the simpler guide example but I am still going through this one, would love to have an explanation of how they used `model.Add`, `model.Minimize` and how to use `model.Maximize`
2. On earlier examples it shows the problems in an algebraic format of finding for values for *x* and *y* etc etc, which I could understand a bit, but how would I go about implementing a system that say for example make the nurse preferably take the same shift as he did the previous time up to an arbitrary maximum limit. Like maybe create a pattern of some sort to evaluate if it fits it.
3. What does the penalty score mean and evaluate to? for example in the list: `weekly_sum_constraints` there is talk of having at list one night-shift per week "penalized" with the value of 3 and a "hard" penalty of 0 (which I assume is a solid rule that could not be broken), what does the value 3 and 0 mean and how are these values chosen?

Thanks for the help, I've been googling up 'constraint programming' trying to understand this but they were no specifically for this library, but I am still searching.

Answer (score 0):

There are no silver bullet answers.

1. read the code. There are no constraints, just modeling. The `constraints` of the model are linear equations, and Boolean constraints (and, or, implication).
2. if you want a specific list of allowed patterns or forbidden ones, you can look at the allowed assignment (forbidden assignment) constraint. See [the doc entry](http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddAllowedAssignments). This constraint is used in this [example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/hidato_sat.py).
3. Look at the penalized version of on soft constraints. It always results in creating a Boolean variable that is true if the penalty should be applied. Then the term bool_var * weight is added to the linear expression in the minimize part.

Comment: Okay then, how about the one where I edited the number of people per shift? why did it fail in the first two days but works in the rest?

Comment: How about the one where I edited the number of people per shift? why did it fail in the first two days but works in the rest?
 1. Isn't the line `model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)` some sort of constraint? Like it sets a rule or something to be followed?

Comment: 2. `AddAllowedAssignments` seems to add a solid rule, what I am asking is a preference for repeated shift designations (i.e. if you started a morning-shift you are more likely to be chosen to have tomorrows morning-shift up until a number of days), or I am not understanding it.

 3. So it is relatively up to infinity? An arbitrary number you can set as some sort of ranking? I was thinking along the lines of a probability value, I can understand it a bit. Thanks